# Сравнительный анализ по скорости работы Java, C++, Assembler

Tags: java, c++, ассемблер, производительность

Добрый день!

Делаю диплом и обоснование того, почему я выбрал язык С++ для написания дипломной работы.
Так вот, одним из пунктов должно быть что-то типа скорость работы или быстрота работы.
Но так не назовешь этот пункт. Ясно что быстрее всего работают проги на ассемблере, потом плюсы, потом джава... Подсобите, как можно назвать пункт в котором проводится это сравнение? Скорость работы? Время выполнения ..., но код в таблицу не вставишь...

Comment: @Alerr, производительность

Comment: а как ее мерить, в чем? время выполнения в мс... Производительность тоже в мс???

Comment: @Alerr, а Вы действительно уверены, что запрограммируете на асме задачку с лучшей производительностью, чем это делает gcc (или g++) -O3 ?

(хотя gcc это просто для примера. Скажем, linpack, собранный  интеловским icc для XEON быстрее, чем собранный gcc).

--

Сразу отвечу на 

     Производительность тоже в мс???

Обычно в попугаях (операциях) в час (единицу времени). Я вполне серьезно.

Comment: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/9/82

Comment: Поправьте свое задание (заново согласуйте с завкафом\начруком) и напишите в исходных данных язык, который вам надо. Тогда выбор можно не обосновывать. 

Это лучше, чем писать обоснование выбора языка на основе среднестатистической температуры в колхозном коровнике за городом или фазы луны.

Comment: @Alerr, а тема диплома какая?

Может оказаться, что С++ просто самый естественный выбор языка для программ, решающих задачи, которые Вы рассматриваете в диполоме.

Кстати, на практике важным фактором выбора языка для решения задачи это *личное пристрастие* программистов (команды (или ее лидера)) к конкретному языку и уровень их знаний в нем.

Не знаю, конечно, способна ли дипломная комиссия (или как они называются?) оценить такую идею.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Неверно утверждение о том, что код на ассемблере работает быстрее всего. Точнее сказать верно только при одновременном соблюдении условий: конкретный процессор, конкретный разработчик, умеющий оптимизировать код под этот процессор. В среднем компилятор лучше знает о всевозможных оптимизациях.

Попробуйте акцентировать внимание на другом:

- C++ - высокоуровневый язык, что позволяет ускорить разработку и упростить поддержку в сравнении с ассемлером;
- C++ - высокоуровневый язык, что позволяет упростить портирование кода на другую платформу в сравнении с ассемблером;
- С++ язык с прямым управлением памятью, что позволяет избежать деградаций в работе приложения, связанных со сборкой мусора в сравнении с языками с автоматическим управлением памятью (Java, С#).

Comment: Сейчас просто обыскался, не могу понять на какое время продают лицензию на VS12, на год?

Comment: насколько мне известно, лицензию на собственно студию вы покупаете бессрочно, но помимо студии ваша лицензия может включать в себя также так называемую подписку MSDN, включающую в себя ряд возможностей по загрузке прочего ПО. Она может действовать до трех лет в зависимости от типа выбранной лицензии

Comment: @Alerr: а зачем вообще ее покупать, особенно студенту? Вроде как Eclipse достаточно возможностей дает.

Answer (score 1):

Пункт можно назвать "Инструменты и технологии". Там подробно описываешь свои инструменты, их преимущества, актуальность и замечательную применимость в проблемной области.

Можно привести статистику каких-нибудь левых исследований или просто обосновать, что нативный код выполняется непосредственно, без необходимости использования различных прослоек, вроде виртуальных машин и JIT-компиляторов, что положительно сказывается на быстродействии.

ЗЫ Все равно тут никаких конкретных цифр ты привести не сможешь.

Comment: @Free_ze,

> Все равно тут никаких конкретных цифр ты привести не сможешь.

Ну почему, можно взять штуки три примера, предварить их рамочкой о том, что это три примера, а не полноценное исследование, и показать скорость выполнения.

Comment: @Fike
Ну синтетика же злостная будет. Может и прокатит на защите, но честнее будет просто рассмотреть отличия технологий.

Answer (score -1):

На C++ написан python, python = 1/2 скорости C++

Comment: Лихо) А как по этой формуле вычислить быстродействие PyPy?

Comment: @djdeniro, строки С++ в [python](http://www.ohloh.net/p/python/analyses/latest/languages_summary) составляют 0.4% от общего объема кода.

Comment: Бред. Во-первых, иррелевантно. Во-вторых, питон может быть написан на любом языке (и таки написан). В-третьих, разница не в два раза. В-четвёртых, разница зависит от реализации. В-пятых, скорость зависит от тестов.

Answer (score -1):

Если задача состоит в выполнении математических операций, существует стандартная мера - количество операций с плавающей точкой в секунду - FLOPS.

Это количество математических действий, нужных для решения задачи, деленное на время работы программы.